# Open a new fancybox after the old one closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I having a trouble with something.
After a password change in fancybox window I correctly open a "Wrong Password" Iframe (if the user give a wrong password).
The problem comes here: After closing the "Wrong Password" Iframe I want to reopen the "Password Change" Iframe. On the "Wrong Password" iframe after checking the password for validity i use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.fancybox.open([
        {
            href: '/pages/messages/wrong_password.asp'
        },
    ], {
        maxWidth: 350,
        maxHeight: 65,
        fitToView: false,
        width: 350,
        height: 65,
        padding: 0,
        scrolling: 'auto',
        preload: true,
        type: 'iframe',
        closeBtn: false,
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.80)'
                }
            }
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $('.pass').fancybox.open;
        }
    });
</script>
```

My fancybox init is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        fitToView: true,
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        padding: 5,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(227,227,227, 0.90)'
                }
            }
        }
    });


    $('.pass').fancybox({
        maxWidth: 560,
        maxHeight: 300,
        fitToView: false,
        type: 'iframe',
        width: 560,
        padding: 0,
        height: 300,
        autoSize: true,
        autoResize: true,
        autoScale: true,
        closeClick: false,
        closeBtn: false,
        openEffect: 'fade',
        openSpeed: 'fast',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        closeSpeed: 'fast',
        scrolling: 'auto',
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                css: {
                    'background': 'rgba(227,227,227, 0.90)'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The .pass class in the one that originally opens the "Change Password" through a link, but I can't pass the href page for that again.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: it will help u: http://jsfiddle.net/Aphjq/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The .pass class in the one that originally 
opens the "Change Password" through a link
```

---

if `.pass` is the *class* of a link, and assuming that the link has its own `href` then you just need to trigger a `click` on that selector.

So instead of this

```
afterClose: function(){
    $('.pass').fancybox.open; // this will never work for sure
}
```

try this

```
afterClose: function(){
    $('.pass').trigger("click");
}
```